# Mysql - Alter table statement to create unique index on long text field

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an `Alter` command to create an `unique_index` on the first 8000 characters.  I'm not able to figure out how to add the 8000 part.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
ALTER TABLE nextractor.tblhtml
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX uniqueindex_InnerHTML (InnerHtml);
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html), you need something like this:

```
alter table <table_name> 
  add unique index <index_name> (<column_name> (8000))
```

---

This is the relevant grammar:

```
| ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
        UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY] [index_name]
        [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
```

and

```
index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]
```

Comment: i tried the alter statment above and it gives me incorrect syntax near (

Comment: @Mike -- I forgot the *extra* parentheses around the column name and length.  It works now.

Comment: When I did this I got the error from MySql saying "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes", So for UTF8 tables it uses 4 bytes per char.  I had my varchar field 255 long, so setting my varchar field to 191 this gave me enough room to create a new unique index.

Answer (score 4):

ALTER TABLE nextractor.tblhtml
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX uniqueindex_InnerHTML (InnerHtml (8000));